# Adding creamer after boiling water vs before

Tags: instant

Hello all I started making instant coffee for the last few months. Due to a combination of laziness and lack of a proper coffee maker. I find that I actually enjoy instant a lot. Normally the process is 2 teaspoons of coffee, add boiling water and then creamer. My question is does the taste amplify if I add creamer before adding the boiling water thus transforming the coffee molecules in a different order?

Thanks!

Comment: is your creamer powder or liquid?

Comment: To clarify, are you talking about mixing the coffee and creamer together before adding the boiling water?

Comment: What kind of coffee? A micro ground from Starbucks is going to behave a bit differently than Nescafe or Folger's Crystals, for instance. This would be much easier to answer if we could experiment :)

Answer (score 2):

I wouldn't say it would amplify it, and you may very well not be able to tell much of a difference. Unless the milk or cream is hot, your coffee won't brew very well (or at least not as fast) on just the milk alone. So by the time you add your hot water, it still shouldn't have dissolved the instant coffee enough to make much of a difference.
If you wanted to experiment, I would try adding some hot cream or milk to the instant coffee first and stirring it up a bit. Still probably wouldn't make much of a difference other than it tasting more like a latte.

Answer (score 2):

Since you want to amplify the taste I would suggest using water that is just about to boil (95°C). I don't have experience with creamer but when I used to drink instant I have always added sugar before water because it helped the coffee to dissolve better. You should experiment with this by using even lower water temperature and watching the dissolution process with and without the creamer.

Answer (score 2):

It's likely better to completely dissolve the coffee before adding creamer. I'm inexperienced with instant, but with regular brewed coffee and tea, the addition of cream impedes the brewing/steeping process.

Comment: Instant coffee is not actually a brew/steep.  It's a rehydration of coffee similar to Mountain House meals.  Adding the instant coffee and creamer together should make little difference.